# Typescript - Declaration Merging for Namespace with Classes

Tags: typescript

I have a Typescript declaration file that looks like the following:

```
/// <reference types="node" />

declare namespace foo {
    interface bar {

    }
}

declare const foo: foo.bar;
export = foo;
```

This compiles just fine with TS 2.0/2.2.  However, if the namespace contains any `class` whatsoever - e.g. changing `bar` to a class, adding another `class bam`, etc. - Typescript throws an error `TS2300: Duplicate identifier 'foo'.`, for the two declare lines.  The goal of the code as written is to take advantage of Declaration Merging in Typescript, and when `foo` contains only `interface`s, the code works as expected (`type`s seem fine to include in `foo`, too).  Why does declaration merging fail if `foo` contains any `class`es?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because `class` is concrete. `namespace` behaves differently when it contains only types or it contains code.

When it contains code, it will also emit value. i.e. `namespace x` would becomes `var x`.

When it does not contain code, no code will be emitted.

That's why when it contains class, it will emit `var foo` thus conflict with your `const foo`.

https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-merging.html

Here is a demo:
http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#src=namespace%20foo%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20interface%20x%20%7B%20%7D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Anamespace%20boo%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20class%20y%20%7B%20%7D%0D%0A%7D